# Underline input if blank

Tags: html, css, input

I want to create an underlined input. So, when the input fills, characters should not be underlined.
Spaces and blanks should be underlined. If I cannot tell, I will give an example.

Is there any solution in html, css or javascript?

```
<input style="letter-spacing:5px;" max-length="9" />
```

And my text is;

> U N D E R L I N E
>
> U N D E R L _ _ _
>
> U N _ E _ L I N E

Comment: please post your full code and also post whatever you have tried.

Comment: looks like we need javascript to do something like this, also we can't style each char in the `input` element, we need another thing like `div` with `contenteditable`.

Comment: @KrupalShah I don't have a code. I want to do something like [this link](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo) , also without masks or limits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought using multiple inputs. Using PHP, or whatever, you could pull this into an array for processing.

[Have an example!](http://jsfiddle.net/ymc1zg19/1/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="U" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" value="E" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" value="R" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" value="L" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" value="I" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" value="E" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled" />
```

CSS

```
input {
    border: none;
    width: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[value=''] {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript function to get desired output. I have slightly modified your input tag

```
<input style="letter-spacing:5px;" maxlength="9" onchange="decoration()" id="thisInput">
```

and my javascript function is

```
function decoration() {
var x=document.getElementById("thisInput").value;
var y="";
for (i=0;i<9;i++) {
    if(x[i]==undefined||x[i]==" " )
    {
        y+="_";
    }
    else {
        y+=x[i];
    }
    }
    document.getElementById("thisInput").value=y;
```

}

Comment: that's a solution, but not good enough in performance. For example mobile browsers. I tried it on "Chrome for Android" and had to write more slowly.